# Workflow set multiple people values to one Person column

Tags: 2010, workflow, person

I have a plain text field with Account Id's I'm trying to set a Person column with these values. I have a Visual Studio workflow doing this. I can insert 1 person but I can't seem to figure out the delimiter for multiple. I seen some things saying a comma will work but I'm getting an `invalid look-up` error with this. And it can't be a semicolon due to the format the Person column expects (see below). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
String acctId = (String)workflowProperties.Item["Account Id"];
String[] stakeHolders = acctId.Split('\n');
String formattedStakeholders = "";

for (int i = 0; i < stakeHolders.Length; i++)
{
  string delimiter = stakeHolders.Length > 1 && i < (stakeHolders.Length - 1) ? ", " : "";

  //The Person column expects: -1;#DOMAIN\USERNAME 
  formattedStakeholders += "-1;#" + stakeHolders[i] + delimiter;
}
```

Comment: did you try a semi colon? that is the default delimiter for adding users through the UI.

Comment: I've tried it but I'm going to try again for the hell of it.

Comment: Ah, i remember, it's a weird way to build a collection, i think this might help: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/multiple-user-insertion-in-sharepoint-list/

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8428774/318776

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs a collection of users passed in, it can be done like so,

> You can use the SPFieldUserValueCollection Class to set a multi value
>   person field:
>
> SPFieldUserValueCollection value = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
>   value.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user1.ID, user1.Name)));
>   value.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, user2.ID, user2.Name)));
>
> objItem["name"] = value; objItem.Update(); Where user1 and user2
>   represent SPUser objects.
>
> If you just have the login names of the user accounts
>
> Tip: To update a single value person field you can just set the user
>   ID:
>
> objItem["name"] = User.ID;

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426660/how-to-insert-data-in-person-or-group-field-using-vs2010/8428774#8428774 also see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/multiple-user-insertion-in-sharepoint-list/

Comment: It would have been great if there's a way to promot some people's comments as answers!